# Buttons do not work in Lua (Corona)

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I have create a game, and the game portion of it is still being worked on. However, the game does work enough to be played. I used a tutorial on corona to learn how to make the menu. The menu displays, and the music plays. However, this error is given:

```
Runtime error
addEventListener: listener cannot be nil: nil
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ?: in function 'getOrCreateTable'
    ?: in function 'addEventListener'
    ?: in function 'addEventListener'
    /Users/jordanmcbride/Desktop/Lua Projects/Tapinator/main.lua:76: in function 'startButtonListeners'
    /Users/jordanmcbride/Desktop/Lua Projects/Tapinator/main.lua:53: in function 'Main'
    /Users/jordanmcbride/Desktop/Lua Projects/Tapinator/main.lua:90: in main chunk
```

Those lines in question are this:

```
function startButtonListeners(action)

   if(action == 'add') then
        playButton:addEventListener('touch', playGame) -- Line 76
        creditsButton:addEventListener('touch', showCredits)
    else
        playButton:removeEventListener('touch', playGame)
        creditsButton:removeEventListener('touch', showCredits)
    end
end
```

LINE 53:

```
startButtonListeners('add')
```

LINE 90:

```
Main()
```

Here is all the code up to that point (excluding game logic):

```
function Main()
    name = display.newImage('title.png', display.contentWidth / 2, 53)
    name:scale( .5, .5 )

    playButton = display.newImage('playButton.png', display.contentWidth / 2, 245)
    playButton:scale( .5, .5 )

    creditsButton = display.newImage('creditsButton.png', display.contentWidth / 2, 305)
    creditsButton:scale( .5, .5 )

    homePage = display.newGroup(name, playButton, creditsButton)

    startButtonListeners('add')
end

local showCredits = {}
function showCredits.touch(e)
    playButton.isVisible = false
creditsButton.isVisible = false
creditsView = display.newImage('credits.png', 0, display.contentHeight)

lastY = name.y
transition.to(name, {time = 300, y = display.contentHeight * 0.5 - title.height - 25})
transition.to(creditsView, {time = 300, y = display.contentHeight * 0.5 + creditsView.height, onComplete = function() creditsView:addEventListener('tap', hideCredits) end})
end

local hideCredits = {}
function hideCredits.touch(e)
    transition.to(creditsView, {time = 300, y = display.contentHeight, onComplete = function() creditsButton.isVisible = true playButton.isVisible = true creditsView:removeEventListener('tap', hideCredits) display.remove(creditsView) creditsView = nil end})
    transition.to(name, {time = 300, y = lastY});
end

function startButtonListeners(action)

    if(action == 'add') then
        playButton:addEventListener('touch', playGame)
        creditsButton:addEventListener('touch', showCredits)
    else
        playButton:removeEventListener('touch', playGame)
        creditsButton:removeEventListener('touch', showCredits)
    end
end
```

Comment: The `playGame` function is not defined, so `playGame` variable is `nil`. Add a definition for the function.

Comment: Thanks @johlo beginner mistakes it seems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As johlo said, the `playGame` function wasn't defined when you add the listeners during the `startButtonListener` function.

In addition, if you're trying to make a menu or UI, try using [widgets](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/index.html) such as the [newButton](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newButton.html) widget. It makes coding the UI a lot easier and there are several effects you can add easily such as changing the button image when the button is being pressed.

Comment: The teacher doesn't want us using anything external... We're supposed to do it "all by hand"

Comment: Well I don't believe widgets are external, they are a feature made available by Corona. Give them a try anyway regardless of what the teacher says, you'll learn to code faster if you just try things out. Don't be limited by what the teacher wants you to do. :)

Comment: Touché, I will look into it. Do you have any reccomendations for websites to learn LUA/Corona? Because i've not found anything of much use... If not, thanks for all the help!

Comment: When I was learning lua/corona, the [Corona Forum](http://forums.coronalabs.com/forum) was pretty helpful. Also their [documentation](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/index.html) shows a lot of help as well.